# Does matlab optimizes SVM linear parameters automatically

Tags: matlab, svm

I am using SVM in Matlab for classification. I directly gave the training data set and class labels for training but without any parameters. My code looks like this:

```
traningData = myData;
label = [1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0];
SVMStructure = svmtrain (myData, label);
... %further prediction part
```

I found the default SVM method is '`linear`', so here in my code, it should be '`linear`' then. But how about the parameter `C`? It says from the Matlab documentation:

```
The resulting structure, SVMstruct, contains the optimized parameters from the SVM algorithm, enabling you to classify new data
```

So does that mean Matlab automatically optimizes the paramter `C` for `linear` SVM here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those built in routines are pretty awful. They allow no flexibility and use dinosaur solvers. It is quite unclear what is going on behind the scenes.

I strongly recommend using another library for SVM training. Many popular packages are free and have MATLAB interfaces.